# Inference speed in tensorflow 2.0 (CPU) for simple models? Vanilla tensorflow/numpy is still 50x faster?

Tags: numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0

Am finding that tensorflow keras (2.0) is still quite slow compared to numpy. Is tfdeploy still in use? What are the options for getting close to numpy speed in inference?

UPDATE:

Here is a cleaned up example showing three methods on a different machine. The tf.function wrapped tensorflow call is now 8x vanilla numpy which is possibly reasonable but still feels like there is some overhead to chase.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(1, 12).astype(np.float32)) # YES! one row only
xnumpy = x.numpy()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, use_bias=False) for i in range(10)
    ])

@tf.function
def f(x):
    return model(x)


def chain_layers_tf(x, kernels):
    y = x
    for kernel in kernels:
        y = tf.matmul(y, kernel)
    return y

# call once
f(x)
chain_layers_tf_wrapped = tf.function(chain_layers_tf)

kernels_tf = [x.kernel for x in model.layers]
kernels_np = [x.kernel.numpy() for x in model.layers]

chain_layers_tf_wrapped(x, kernels_np)
chain_layers_tf_wrapped(x, kernels_tf)

def chain_layers_np(x, kernels):
    y = x
    for kernel in kernels:
        y = y.dot(kernel)
    return y

model(x)

"""
%timeit t.model(t.x)
%timeit t.f(t.x)
%timeit t.chain_layers_tf(t.x, t.kernels_tf)
%timeit t.chain_layers_tf_wrapped(t.x, t.kernels_tf)
%timeit t.chain_layers_np(t.xnumpy, t.kernels_np)
"""

# In [107]: %timeit t.model(t.x)
#      ...: %timeit t.f(t.x)
#      ...: %timeit t.chain_layers_tf(t.x, t.kernels_tf)
#      ...: %timeit t.chain_layers_tf_wrapped(t.x, t.kernels_tf)
#      ...: %timeit t.chain_layers_np(t.xnumpy, t.kernels_np)
# 1.51 ms ± 1.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 131 µs ± 856 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 491 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 417 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 5.21 µs ± 7.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Previous notes:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
Not just numpy as above, but tensorflow is faster than tensorflow.keras

In [22]: x = np.random.randn(100, 12).astype(np.float32)

In [23]: a = np.random.randn(12, 16).astype(np.float32)

In [24]: %timeit tf.matmul(x, a)
39.3 µs ± 98.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


UPDATE: 

more layers not much different
```

[image]

Comment: This comparison is kind of meaningless, try making a comparison of a complex model with multiple layers. Also numpy does not support GPU inference.

Comment: Even multiple layers with branches won't be that much different. I am not going to make a model with 1000 layers. 

It looks like tflite might be order of microseconds. Haven't quite got it totally working well yet though.

Comment: Why would you want GPU inference for a small model? 

@MatiasValdenegro you need to consider specific cases of simulating paths (for example), you would calling the model MANY times but not in a batch.

I think there is something in the python setup that is slow on each call.

I will update with another example and change the title to "tensorfflow is still 1000x faster than tensorflow. Since it is fast with vanilla tf.matmul

Comment: Are you sure TensorFlow doesn't compile anything during your m.prediction and so on? What if you timeit it again right after? What if you increase data size 100x?

Comment: Moreover, if TF calculates on GPU and numpy on CPU, the difference is logical. GPUs are much slower on small amount of data

Comment: This is about TF on CPU ... I should clarify. Will update.